# Libgdx Mouse just clicked

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to get when the mouse just clicked, not when the mouse is pressed.
I mean I use a code in a loop and if I detect if the mouse is pressed the code will execute a lot of time, but I want execute the code only Once, when the mouse has just clicked.

This is my code :

```
if (Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)){

            //Some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputEvent - you need to handle input events instead of polling, by extending InputProcessor and passing your custom input processor to Gdx.input.setInputProcessor().

EDIT:

```
public class MyInputProcessor implements InputProcessor {
   @Override
   public boolean touchDown (int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
      if (button == Input.Buttons.LEFT) {
          // Some stuff
          return true;     
      }
      return false;
   }
}
```

And wherever you want to use that:

```
MyInputProcessor inputProcessor = new MyInputProcessor();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputProcessor);
```

If find it easier to use this pattern:

```
class AwesomeGameClass {
    public void init() {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputProcessor() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
                if (button == Input.Buttons.LEFT) {
                    onMouseDown();
                    return true;
                }
                return false
            }
            
            ... the other implementations for InputProcessor go here, if you're using Eclipse or Intellij they'll add them in automatically ...
        });
    }
    
    private void onMouseDown() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me more detail about what function I should use ? in the InputEvent, I don't see where is the function that I need.

Comment: I need to check when the mouse just clicked, meaning that even't if the mouse is pressed for a long time, the code will execute only ONE TIME, when the mouse has just clicked

Comment: Yes, InputProcessor will do this for you. Editing the answer to provide more detail soon.

Comment: For the easy use I think there was something like: Gdx.input.justTouched(). Not sure if this could be useful

Answer (score 11):

You can use `Gdx.input.justTouched()`, which is true in the first frame where the mouse is clicked. Or, as the other answer states, you can use an InputProcessor (or InputAdapter) and handle the `touchDown` event:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter() {
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        if (button == Buttons.LEFT) {
            // do something
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Without InputProcessor you can use easy like this in your render loop:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    if(Gdx.input.isButtonJustPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)){
        //TODO:
    }
}
```